# Ruby form_for html attributes not working, multipart or id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, multipart

I am desperately trying to put a multipart to my form in Ruby but it won't show up. I looked up online everywhere but whatever I try it doesn't show. Even simple IDs or classes won't work...

Is there any dependency I am not aware of?

```
<%= form_for @listing, :html => {:id => "account_form", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :highlights %>
      <%= f.text_area :highlights, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :location %>
      <%= f.text_area :location, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :catering %>
      <%= f.text_area :catering, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :travel %>
      <%= f.text_area :travel, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :dates %>
      <%= f.text_area :dates, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :price %>
      <%= f.text_field :price, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :category %>
      <%= f.select :category, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :include_blank => true %>

      <%= f.label :country %>
      <%= f.text_field :country, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :url %>
      <%= f.text_field :url, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :photo %>
      <%= f.file_field :photo %>

  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

which will result in the following HTML

```
<form class="new_listing" id="new_listing" action="/listings" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should change to multipart by itself when you add [`f.file_field`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/file_field) call:

> Using this method inside a form_for block will set the enclosing form’s encoding to multipart/form-data.

As was found out in comments, error was due to using `@listing` inside of partial (instead of local variable).

If you have `_listing_form.html.erb` partial, you should [pass the local variables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables) manually:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/listing_form', locals: {listing: @listing} %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't

Comment: Well it should. Provide your full form source code.

Comment: Put it into an answer above. I also tried it with just the file_field tag and nothing else except the submit, without the class. Still the same result

Comment: Please move it to your question instead. Or create [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and give a link in your question.

Comment: I digged a little deeper. Since the form is a partial I integrated it into another view where the multipart/form-data suddenly shows up. Don't know what is in the other view to keep the form producing the multipart/form-data?

Comment: @Freebian Well, mystery resolved then. In your partial you should use `listing` instead of `@listing` (and if your partial's name is not `_listing.html.erb` you should also manually set an object: `render partial: 'listing_form', object: @listing`). Your `@listing` variable was `nil` inside of partial, that's why form wasn't rendering correctly.

Comment: Mhh, that would explain it. But it doesn't work. My partial is under shared/_listing_form.html.erb If I use just listing it says undefined even if I declare the object as you mentioned. It works if I render the form on a static page and is not working if I render it on a view inside the listing controller

Comment: @Freebian I've updated my answer. Also, I suggesting you read the section of guide via the link I provided.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now, but I also realized that there was another form tag inside the one view. Stupid little mistake too. Anyway, great support. Thanks!